# Injection of the LoggerInterface

Tags: symfony, logging

I want to log inside my controller. Reading the documention, I injected the loggerInterface in my function like it is written :

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class MyDefaultController extends Controller {
   public function myAction(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger) {
     ....
     $logger->error('blabla');
}
```

it used to work but obviously I have changed something (dont know what exactly) and now I have this error :

```
Argument 2 passed to myAction must implement Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, none given, called in myProject/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php on line 195
```

it is like the interface is not automatically injected like it was before.

Can u help with that ?

ty

Command line debug:container logger :

```
// This service is an alias for the service monolog.logger

Information for Service "monolog.logger"
========================================

 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------    
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       monolog.logger
  Class            Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
  Tags             -
  Calls            pushProcessor, useMicrosecondTimestamps, pushHandler, 
                   pushHandler, pushHandler
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------------
```

didnt know I have Monolog already installed, I thought you had to use composer to have it.

Comment: Could you please paste here `services.yaml` file content (section `_defaults` and `App\Controller\:`)?

Comment: dont have that but did not have before

Comment: so what should I add ?

Comment: what does your `bin/console debug:container logger` say?

Comment: I dont want to use Monolog but just the  minimalist PSR-3 logger already in Symfony

Comment: well you can always add the interface to your services.yaml (under services obviously): `Psr\Log\LoggerInterface: { class: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\Logger }` and it should be injected whenever the interface is type-hinted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I had to do in service.yml

```
 _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

thank you everyone.

Comment: thought that's the initial state of the services.yaml, but apparently false assumption ;o/